# I'm trying to display MySQL queries in a web browser using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to run MySQL commands through Python source code and have it display in my web browser.
When I compile the code in an editor (Komodo Edit) it complies and returns the expected set of rows, but when I try to view in a browser the source code is displayed, not the query result I seek...
Here's what I have...

```
import mysql.connector
conn = None

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host="localhost", user="jump", password="secret")
    print('Connected to MySQL!')
except Exception as ex:
    print('cannot connect to MySQL : exception : ' + str(ex))

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.close()
print('terminating connection with MySQL')
conn.close()
```

...I'm pretty sure the source is good, and that somewhere I missed a configuration step or some such. 
   I can get my command prompt to open the source file and display the query results, so I've got a connection between Python and MySQL server, which I verified through the MySQL workbench also.

Thanks for any help y'all can give!
-M

Comment: Remove `conn = None` and put the last 4 lines inside the `try` statement.
Please provide more details like what is the output/error.. so that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: @Arihant, THank you for the response! I tried your recommendation and it returned the same result. Which is... import mysql.connector
try:
 conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host="localhost", user="jump", password="secret")
 print('Connected to MySQL!')
...

Comment: @Arihant (con't) ...the web browser displays the source code. The part I don't understand is why I can get my IDE(Komodo Edit) to display, in the console output pane in the IDE, the query results as desired, but not thrugh the we browser as one would use Python queries to query an actual database. -M

Comment: What web server are you using to host your python script?  It sounds like you're just putting file://path/to/my/python_script.py in a web browser and expecting it to run.  You need to have a server that can interpret python for it to actually run your code.